# Why does angular material table sort break when I change where I set this.dataSource.sort

Tags: angular, angular-material

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219496/angular-material-table-sort-not-working-when-using-http-get) I was told that if I wanted to sort an angular material table that was populated from an `http.get()` request, I would have to set the sort after the response returned (e.g. in the `subscribe()`). This makes sense to me.

However, after playing around with it a bit, I tried to modify my original Stackblitz to set the sort for the angular material table that was populated from inline static json in the same way, in the `subscribe()`. This broke the sort for this table.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pvmzbs

Before:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.name === 'Inline') {
      this.api.getDataInline().subscribe((response) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
      });
    } else if (this.name === 'Http') {
      this.api.getDataHttp().subscribe((response) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

After:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.name === 'Inline') {
      this.api.getDataInline().subscribe((response) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });
    } else if (this.name === 'Http') {
      this.api.getDataHttp().subscribe((response) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {}
```

Why does this break the sort for the inline table?

Comment: You are not getting value for 'sort' in the Inline style.

Comment: Can you clarify? How is it different from the http style?

Comment: Change this: '.getDataInline().subscribe((response) => {  console.log('response inline sort:', this.sort);..' and '.getDataHttp().subscribe((response) => { console.log('response Http sort:', this.sort);' and then you will see that 'this.sort' will be 'undefined' for inline. Unfortunately, I can't tell you why.

Comment: I can see that you're correct about this.sort being undefined in the inline branch, but I am no closer to understanding why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other answer, the static data arrives before the view has been rendered, thus it is undefined. You can provide `{ static: true }` in `ViewChild`. You need to set that for being able to run your code in `OnInit`.

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort!: MatSort;
```

Your forked **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b3sxhq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

Replace `ngOnInit` with `ngAfterViewInit`.
In the `OnInit` call `sort` was not yet initialized, in `AfterViewInit` you are sure that elements from the template are initialized as well.
And the Http table was working because matSort was not yet initialized during the first subscription, but then on the second probably it already was.